# Force obj-c to throw an exception when accessing a nil property

Tags: objective-c, lldb

I get caught out way too many times by creating eg an `NSMutableArray* myArray` property and then forgetting to assign `self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array];` in `-init`. My app of course never complains in such cases because `[self.myArray addObject:foo]` is perfectly legal if `self.myArray` is `nil`, so I'm left scratching my head and going "double you tee eff".

I realise this is a long shot, but is there an lldb attribute or property specifier that would cause obj-c to ensure that properties are non-nil after completing `-init`?

Comment: In my experience, those bugs will always appear in Obj-C code. However, they are the simplest to find and debug. Usually, when I make an error like this and I see some unexpected behaviour in the app, it takes me only seconds to realize what went wrong.

Comment: @Sulthan it's 2014 and I would like my compiler to be smarter.

Comment: Compilers cannot find a semantic error. For what the compiler knows, calling methods on `nil` is perfectly valid. You cannot make it to distiguish when it's valid and when it's not. You can add all types of asserts but you will always forget to add the assert somewhere. It's a language feature, you can't find a global "fix".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSMutableArray*) myArray
{
    NSAssert(nil != _myArray);
    return _myArray;
}
```

You can write this implementation of `myArray` accessor.

Also you can add in yours class method something like that:

```
- (void) AssertValid
{
    NSAssert(nil != _myArray);
}
```

Comment: Yoda conditions? Why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a compiler flag that will help you, however you could change the semantics of your array access so it goes through your own methods instead of directly to the `NSMutableArray`.

So instead of

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property NSMutableArray *array
@end
```

use:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
- (void)addObject:(id)object;
- (NSUInteger)objectCount;
- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end
```

and you can add whatever checks you like to those array access methods (as well as lazily creating the array, of course).

However, as you can see, this could be add significant effort just to solve a small issue, and I wouldn't do this myself :)

Comment: Yeah, agreed this is not really ideal. Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such mechanism and don't think it exists, because it would make little practical sense as there are many classes whose properties are `nil` most of the time by design.

It is possible to perform this check using `class_copyPropertyList()` from objc-runtime and then reading every property by name (for example, using `valueForKey:`). In simplest case, you would create a category method like `[self logNilProperties]` on `NSObject` and call it at the end of `init...` methods of classes that you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible. It's a language feature. You can't just change the behavior of the language.

Probably the best solution you can get is to introduce unit tests for the values of your properties. Or asserts:

`assert(self.property != nil)`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a small piece of code which is used to throw an Exception.

```
 NSException *exception=[[NSException alloc]initWithName:@"no result" reason:@"array empty" userInfo:nil];
    [exception raise];
```

The exception can be caught in the AppDelegate file

```
void exceptionHandler(NSException *exception){

}
```

Before this method write

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&exceptionHandler);
```

in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Happy Coding :)